# what function/package conflicts with dplyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

dplyr used to work without issue, recently it seems to be in conflict with some other package I loaded. I didn't use `plyr` or `MASS`.

```
 mtcars%>%select(mpg)
```

> Error in select(., mpg) : unused argument (mpg)

Why is it giving this error?

Comment: Try loading them in a different order -- dplyr last.  Also try running `conficts()` and then for each conflict found `find("X")` where X is the name of a function that conflicts.

Comment: `select` in `dplyr` conflicts with `select` in `MASS`. Even if you haven't loaded `MASS`, you might have loaded one of the many packages that depend on `MASS` (see "reverse depends" on the [CRAN MASS package page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html)) and that therefore load `MASS` functions into the global environment.

Comment: @eipi10 thanks, that could be why, does it solve the issue if i always load dplyr last?

Comment: I believe so...

Comment: `raster::select`

Comment: and `raster::extract`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into a similar problem with an R script in Azure Databricks.  To solve the issue I installed the R `conflicted` package, called the library and then ran my code.  A message then appears in the console window which indicated that the `dplyr` `mutate` function was  conflicting with the one from `sparkR`.  To easily resolve this, you can tell R which package to default to with the `conflict_prefer()` function and passing it the arguments of the conflicting function name and the preferred/default package to use when a conflict arises.  So for example:

**Step 1. Install conflicted and attach it**

```
install.packages("conflicted")
library(conflicted)
```

**#Step 2.  Run your code that might contain a conflict with packages you've already attached**

(Note:  I'm using R 4.1, which uses the new pipe operator |> instead of %>% in older versions:

```
cars |> mutate(log_dist=log(dist))
```

In my case, this produced the following output to my console/log:

```
Error:
! [conflicted] `mutate` found in 2 packages.
Either pick the one you want with `::` 
 * SparkR::mutate
 * dplyr::mutate
Or declare a preference with `conflict_prefer()`
 * conflict_prefer("mutate", "SparkR")
 * conflict_prefer("mutate", "dplyr")
```

**#Step 3. Modify your code to tell R which package to use when function conflicts arise among packages**

```
conflict_prefer("mutate", "dplyr")
cars |> mutate(log_dist=log(dist))
```

And the result is then as expected with no errors/warnigns:

```
   speed dist  log_dist
1      4    2 0.6931472
2      4   10 2.3025851
3      7    4 1.3862944
4      7   22 3.0910425
.
.
.
```

Of course, you can always explicitly tell R which library to use with:

```
cars |> dplyr::mutate(log_dist=log(dist))
```

Answer (score 3):

`SparkR` also conflicts with `select` (`object 'mpg' not found`)

Instead of having to remember in which order to load the packages, you can also use

`mtcars %>% dplyr::select(mpg)`

when you run into these conflicts.