# How to determine the source of a function conflict in R

Tags: r

I am working on a large project with many libraries. I am running into a function conflict with `dplyr::select()`. Clearly there is another library loaded somewhere that also has a `select()` function. How can I figure out which one?

```
> iris %>% select("Species")
Error in select(., "Species") : unused argument ("Species")
```

(I know in this particular case the conflict is caused by `MASS::select()` and I can avoid it with `dplyr::select("Species")` but I want to know how to tell which package R is going to in general when there is a conflict.)

This question is different from [what function/package conflicts with dplyr in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43308279/what-function-package-conflicts-with-dplyr-in-r) because I am asking more generally how to find the cause of a function conflict, not the specific cause of the `select()` conflict. Some answers may be the same but readers will not know that from the question title.

Comment: Try `getAnywhere(x = "select")`

Comment: See [list of masked functions in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6354697/list-of-masked-functions-in-r)

Comment: I get this particular conflict with `MASS`, which could be loaded by some other package.

Comment: If you type in `select`, after dumping the function it ends with something like `<environment: namespace:...>`, where `...` indicates the package in which the function was found (per the search path). Alternatively, you can bypass seeing the function body with `environment(select)`, which should just tell you the environment/namespace.

Comment: Wow, these functions are game changers... wish I knew them earlier!

Comment: @r2evans Perfect, that is the simplest, most direct approach.

Comment: @NelsonGon The dupe doesn't answer the question, like the OP mentions in his last paragraph.

Comment: @Rui Barradas Retracted! Original post was edited I guess. In any case, the comments on that post are quite useful. Would be great if they made a community answer out of them.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that was an edit in response to the dupe suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

The [conflicted](http://cran.r-project.org/package=conflicted) package is helpful, loaded either before or after the conflict occurs (or you know about it!)

```
> iris %>% select("Species")
Error in select(., "Species") : unused argument ("Species")
> library(conflicted)
> iris %>% select("Species")
Error: [conflicted] `select` found in 2 packages.
Either pick the one you want with `::`
* MASS::select
* dplyr::select
Or declare a preference with `conflict_prefer()`
* conflict_prefer("select", "MASS")
* conflict_prefer("select", "dplyr")
```

Base R also offers conflict awareness when libraries are loaded, described in the "Conflicts" section of the help page `?library`. This can be a useful solution to resolving conflicts once they've been discovered.